# It is possible to run a Microsoft Office application in a docker container?

Tags: docker

I'm starting to study containerization in docker, but i'm wondering about this,    "if we can run a libreOffice application in a docker container, so,  coud we run a Microsoft Office application in a Docker container? "
pd: sorry im noob.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Juan. Hope you find many answers here in the future. The short answer to your questions is: Yes. containers can run full x11 / Windows UI applications. The Longer version is: Yes, but why? Containerization is meant for process isolation. Windows apps are not great at single process applications. As well, the overhead the running container would require AND the requirement to network connect into the container to access the application. Not impossive, just probably not worth the effort.